# Mysql - How to get unique users who earned points in specific range quarterly?

Tags: mysql

I have below mysql table

```
tbl_user_points

id  userid  points  add_date
1   1       10      2015-01-20
2   2       20      2015-11-13
3   3       30      2015-02-24
4   4       40      2015-07-21
5   1       50      2015-01-10
6   6       60      2015-12-01
7   7       70      2015-07-06
8   8       80      2015-06-14
9   9       90      2015-04-10
10  1       100     2015-09-08
11  3       110     2015-01-07
```

I want to fetch unique users who earned points in below range quarterly:

```
Under 100 PTS
100-249 PTS
250-499 PTS
500-999 PTS
OVER 1000 PTS
```

NOTE:

```
Quarter 1 - 01-01-2015 to 31-01-2015
Quarter 2 - 01-04-2015 to 30-06-2015
Quarter 3 - 01-07-2015 to 30-09-2015
Quarter 4 - 01-10-2015 to 31-12-2015
```

I am trying to get result with below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( user_id ) AS totalUserCnt FROM tbl_user_points WHERE  db_add_date >=  '2015-01-01' AND db_add_date <= '2015-03-31' HAVING SUM(points) < 100
```

Comment: you want these to all be selected in the same table? do you want individual users, or the number of users per quarter per range?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(points) FROM tbl_user_points WHERE db_add_date >= '2015-01-01' AND db_add_date <= '2015-03-31' GROUP BY user_id HAVING SUM(points) > 0 AND SUM(points) < 100
```

Change the values as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question but in order to get it for each quarter you have to add the `QUARTER()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( user_id ) AS totalUserCnt FROM tbl_user_points
  WHERE  db_add_date >=  '2015-01-01' AND db_add_date <= '2015-12-31' 
  GROUP BY QUARTER(add_date)
  HAVING SUM(points) < 100
```